# Magento, url duplication , seo

Tags: magento, url, seo, duplicates

I have a website in magento and i am facing a problem that there are 2 url that are being generated for same product and that is creating problem for the SEO of that website.

when we are adding a new product then 2 urls are beign generated for this 
for example :

http://mydomain.com/featured-products/loose-fitted-antique-brown-leather-jacket-for-men.html

and
http://mydomain.com/loose-fitted-antique-brown-leather-jacket-for-men.html

so kindly suggest me a solution for this problem

Comment: Look up Canonical urls

Comment: Where i will find this url

Answer (score 0):

Goto System->Configuration->Catalog->Search Engine Optimization  and set Use Categories Path for Product URLs to No.